# Clear or Set up Boot Menu on old laptop Fujitsu A572/e

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

i want to clear the boot menu. There is no other OSes on this machine except Kubuntu. But the boot menu shown previously installed OSes.
I tried installed grub, but i cant boot into Kubuntu after that, it just showing terminal like. And i have no idea afterwards. And just start installing new Kubuntu.

The first OS installed on this device is Windows 7.
Then Win10 and Android x86.
Then Ubuntu, and current OS is just Kubuntu.

### My Devices

- FUJITSU Lifebook A572/e with Core I5 3320m
- Phoenix Motherboard
- Bios F2
- Boot Menu F12

---

Any idea? Need more specific information?
Thank you

[Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqTUs.jpg)

Comment: The first boot OS is shown as 'ubuntu'. If you select 'ubuntu', what does that boot to?

Comment: @PaulBenson boot into Kubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it is the UEFI boot menu.
In a Linux terminal, use the command `efibootmgr`:

`efibootmgr -v` lists available boot entries.

`efibootmgr -b 0002 -B` would remove entry number 2 from the menu.

See this [Gentoo documentation page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! It was UEFI boot menu.